# Not able to backup couchbase bucket - error 'mt could not find index server:0'

Tags: couchbase

After killing the backup processes (because of high cpu usage), I'm trying to execute the backup again (through linux terminal) and it fails. the error is:
"mt could not find index server:0"

I am Not sure why it's looking for an index server.

My command is 
/opt/couchbase/bin/cbbackup couchbase://localhost:8091 /opt/couchbase/backup/backupFolder -m diff --single-node -u {username}-p {password}

Comment: Kill all running cbbackup processes and try again

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: What version of Couchbase? This seems to be a known issue on 4.x, but fixed in 5.x - https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-19956